# Python Matrix multiplication for making grid

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Is there any simple way/command in Python to make two (or three) matrix multiplications to get Product Kernel, e.g. expanding for grid ? I mean points should be evaluated for each combination of grid.

I have two solutions, however first is made using loops (unacceptable in my case) and the other is doing reshaping of input before multiplication (hardcoded and works for product of 2 kernels and need adjustments if to be used for 3,4, etc Kernels).

First solution:

```py
for xi, xg in enumerate(xgrid):
    for yi, yg in enumerate(ygrid):
    kde[xi, yi] = 1 / ndata * np.sum(kernel1(xg) * kernel2(yg))
```

Where kernel1(xg) * kernel2(yg) is vector for example (1, 10000), where data points are evaluated at each gridpoint xg and yg. So we are actually building the grid calculating product step by step.

Second solution, where "fullkernel" is already an object of evaluating data on grid:

```py
kde = np.zeros(shape=(98, 98)) # 98 is length of grid
X_out = np.repeat(fullkernel[0], len(fullkernel[0]), axis=0)
Y_out = np.tile(fullkernel[1], (len(fullkernel[1]), 1))
testing = 1 / len(fullkernel[0]) * np.sum(X_out * Y_out, axis=1)
f = np.reshape(testing.T, kde.shape)
```

shape of fullkernel is (2, 98, 9999), where 2 is two different datasets, 98 grid points and 9999 data points.

So in the end I need matrix of size (9604, 9999) which is similar to X_out * Y_out in example above but without reshaping and tiling initial data. Is there way to get this matrix with some command using fullkernel[0] and fullkernel[1]  only without any additional preparations?

Comment: Can you post some example toy input and expected output data?

Comment: isn't this what [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is for?

Comment: Hi, guys. Just solved by myself. Thanks anyway for replying. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have find solution to this by trial and error. If it helps others:

`res = 1 / len(fullkernel[0][0]) * np.sum(fullkernel[0][:, None, :] * fullkernel[1], axis=2)`

The result of mutliplication is cube 98*98*9999. Creating one more dimension is a key to make multiplication be "meshgridlike", e.g. fixing one grid point xg and running through all other grid points of y, and then repeating it all again for other gridpoints of x.

And after summing across columns res is of shape 98*98 which is what I need. It took 0.7 seconds to run for 2 datasets of 10000 points and 2 grids on len=98 each.
For loop took 2.7 seconds. 
Tile/repeat approach 1.6 seconds.